# create backup file descriptor?

Tags: c, unix

```
  stdinBackup = 4;
  dup2(0, stdinBackup);
```

Currently I am doing the above to 'backup' stdin so that it can be restored from backup later after it has been redirected somewhere else. I have a feeling that I am doing a lot wrong? (eg arbitrarily assigning 4 is surely not right). Anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

If you  just want to make a general copy for your own use, there is no need to use `dup2()`. Just use a plain `dup()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int stdinBackup = dup(STDIN_FILENO);
```

You only need to use `dup2()` when you care about the duplicate's actual value.

See [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stdin.html) for the definition of the symbolic constant `STDIN_FILENO`, which is far better than using a naked `0` in the code.

Comment: I see no reason to use `STDIN_FILENO` in place of 0 when 0 is fixed for all-time by POSIX.

Comment: @R..: Not even for readability? I'd say that STDIN_FILENO is a lot more helpful than a plain 0 when it comes to communicating what is going on. Avoid magical numbers, and all that.

Comment: I dunno about you, but my eyes/brain can more easily and quickly distinguish 0/1/2 than they can dig the xxx (IN/OUT/ERR) out of the ugly, all-caps STDxxx_FILENO.